# Java - why is a method from a static block not getting loaded in time?

Tags: java, multithreading, testing, java-8, race-condition

I wrote a method `processMetrics` that loads new metrics if the files containing the data were updated since the last request. I wanted the method to get executed every 10 seconds so decided to use `ExecutorService` for that purpose.

However when I'm testing a method from the class that's using the config. I can see that the method is invoked without the configuration being loaded by the executor from the static block. 
When I'm running the test without first calling the commented line it returns false since no config was updated.
But when I run `MetricsProcessor.isMetricValid("Metric_1");` and then `assertTrue(MetricsProcessor.isMetricValid("Metric_1"))`; the config is loaded and the test returns true.

What could cause such a behaviour? I came to a conclusion that it's because the `MetricsProcessor` class is not getting loaded in time. Is it a valid assumption?

Also, I've managed to fix the problem by explicitly calling `processMetrics();` in the first line of the static block before the executor. But still not clearly understand why is this happening?

```
@Test
    public void testIsMetricValid() {
//        MetricsProcessor.isMetricValid("Metric_1");
        assertTrue(MetricsProcessor.isMetricValid("Metric_1"));
    }


// MetricsProcessor is a final class
private static Runnable loadMetrics = MetricsProcessor::processMetrics;
private static ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

static {
        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(processMetrics, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

private static void processMetrics() {
 {
            long metricsLastMod = metricsFile.lastModified();

            if (metricsLastMod > lastMod.get()) {
                processMetricsData(metricsFile);
            lastMod.set(metricsLastMod);
            }
}
```

Comment: Could you show your isMetricValid method?

Comment: This seems to be a pretty standard race condition. You have a thread that you're calling the test from and you have your executor service. There is a race condition between when the executor executes your 'loadMetrics' task and when the main thread calls testIsMetricValid.

Comment: @NikNik `isMetricValid` method iterates a keySet of the config map and does a very simple check: `StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(metric, metricFromConf)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're facing race conditions. There are two threads:

- loading your class and then running tests
- executing scheduled tasks

In some circumstances the scheduler may start faster than your tests. But there is no guarantee. So in order to prevent race conditions you need to ensure at least the first execution of your task.

This is one of the solutions:

```
private static Runnable loadMetrics = MetricsProcessor::processMetrics;
private static ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

static {
    loadMetrics.run();
    // Note the updated initial delay. 
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(loadMetrics, 10, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Comment: Am I correct that the first thread that you've mentioned `loading class and then running tests` - is loading both `MetricsProcessor` and `MetricsProcessorTest` classes?

Comment: In this particular case the answer is *yes*. But there is no guarantee. The idea of concurrent code is that you're responsible for avoiding locks and race conditions.